# Cancel Ajax request or take the last one

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a search bar which show a result from content of the `input`. Therefore, **i send a `request ajax` when the user press a key in the `input`**.

However, if my `request` is too long to load a big result with many element ( like `Red` ), it remplace my small and precisly result ( like `Red Small Square` ) writed after.

I need to know how cancel a `ajax` before send a new `request` or how to take the last one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var content = $( 'div#result' );

    $( 'input#search' ).keyup( function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'jquery/search.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $( this ).serialize()
        }).done(function ( data ) {
            content.empty().append(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use [`abort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#abort%28%29) method, assign ajax object into variable and check if variable not `null` see below sample code

```
var xhr = null;
 $( 'input#search' ).keyup( function() {
        if(xhr !== null){
             xhr.abort();
             xhr = null;
        }
        xhr = $.ajax({
            url: 'jquery/search.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $( this ).serialize()
        }).done(function ( data ) {
            content.empty().append(data);
        });
    });
```

Comment: It should be noted it won't avoid server to still processing previous aborted request. BTW, `content.empty().append(data);` is equivalent to `content.html(data);`

Answer (score -4):

use "async" option in jquery ajax call (true|false)

Comment: Sorry no, or my website blocking every key pressed.

Comment: Using async `false` would solve the problem but would also block the UI for as long as the request is running. It wouldn’t abort but just continue running and only then would the user be able to input the next character. Certainly undesirable.

Comment: Moreover, it is in general a bad idea to use `async: false` in AJAX call. You should avoid it and I see no practical case, when it is necessary. First "A" in AJAX stands for "asynchronous". Synchronous asynchonous call is some sort of bad thing.

Comment: you can also use abort() of jQuery.ajax